# Is there any precedent wherein both parties require a burden of proof?

Tags: burden-of-proof

My thinking is with respect to very serious issues wherein getting the correct resolution is very important.  Usually the burden seems to be on one party or another, but I wonder if there are cases or situations where both parties are burdened with justifying their positions?

Comment: I may be mistaken but aren't all cases like this? The plaintiff must argue their position and the defendant theirs... Jack sues Alice for not delivering on time and Alice defends her position by saying Jack kept changing colors. It's on Jack to prove he was allowed to do that and Alice must prove that he was not. They both have burden of proof...

Comment: Both parties may present evidence, but normally the burden is on only one,or on only one at a given point in time. When a party shows a *prima facie* case, the burden may shift to the defense to disprove it. If the defense shows plausible evidence of an active defense, the burden may shift back to disprove or counter the defense.

Comment: @DavidSiegel Is this the "burden of production" in Ohwilleke's answer?

Comment: @zibadawa timmy pretty much, or one form of it at least.

Comment: So then what would happen if neither party shows any evidence at all?  They somehow both lose?

Comment: There would need to be a ruling when both parties fail to meet their burden of proof, so ultimately you need to place the (initial) burden on one party or the other (and this burden may shift as parties meet their burden). You don't have a burden of proof placed on you when the court would find in your favour if you do nothing.

Comment: @NotThatGuy: Could both parties bear the burden of having to prove that they should not be cited for contempt for wasting the court's time?

Comment: To clarify, the situation I was thinking about was Climate Change.  There are some people that think the human activity is not a factor (or maybe it isn't even happening at all) and there are some that think it is happening.  Which side has the burden of proof?  My thinking is that since it is so important to get "right" (the right answer) that both sides are burdened.

Comment: @Jiminion Climate change is a scientific claim (or a set of claims), not a legal case. There may be lawsuits related to climate change, but the burden of proof would depend on the details of each lawsuit. As for scientific claims, the "burden" would relate to figuring out whether it's the hypothesis that best explains the evidence. There may be an expectation on the person first making the claim, to make a compelling case, but it's more of a collaborative effort (unlike lawsuits, which are competitive), and anyone can present evidence one way or the other, to try to figure out the truth.

Comment: @supercat I'm not aware of there generally being much of a burden on the defence, because one's right to legally defend oneself is quite important (even when one's defence is quite bad). Although perhaps it depends on the type of legal case.

Answer (score 11):

**Are there cases or situations where both parties are burdened with justifying their positions?**

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

Yes, but different standards are applied.

One example is the "reverse burden of proof" placed on the defendant in [section 1(1)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Eliz2/1-2/14/section/1?timeline=false) of the Prevention of Crime Act 1953:

> Any person who without lawful authority or reasonable excuse, **the proof whereof shall lie on him**, has with him in any public place any offensive weapon shall be guilty of an offence...

The prosecution have to prove "beyond a reasonable doubt" that the article is actually an offensive weapon and that the named defendant possessed it on a particular date and that s/he was in a public place at the time.

Whereas the standard of proof for the defendant to show they had lawful authority or a reasonable excuse for having  is the, lower, "balance of probabilities".

Similar legislation, for a similar offence, at [section 139](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/33/section/139?timeline=false) of the Criminal Justice Act 1988 states that:

> (4)It shall be a defence for a person charged with an offence under this section **to prove that he had good reason or lawful authority for having the article** with him in a public place.
>
> (5)Without prejudice to the generality of subsection (4) above, it shall be a defence for a person charged with an offence under this section to prove that he had the article with him—
>
> - (a)for use at work;
> - (b)for religious reasons; or
> - (c)as part of any national costume.

Which, again, is on the balance of probabilities. See, for example, [R v Lambert [2001] UKHL 37](https://www.casemine.com/judgement/uk/5b46f1ee2c94e0775e7ee5a7?locale=en_UK):

> If [a legal burden of proof on an accused] is created the matter in question must be taken as proved against the accused unless he satisfies the jury on a balance of probabilities to the contrary...

Comment: Do these laws specify “balance of probabilities” for these particular defenses anywhere? Or is that a general thing for defendants, or even a general default to which the “beyond a reasonable doubt” standard is, despite being the best-known standard, actually an exception?

Answer (score 7):

Generally speaking, the ultimate burden of proof is placed upon one party or another. But sometimes there is what is called a "burden of production" that involves some evidentiary showing that an issue is present before the burden of proof is implicated.

For example, no evidence needs to be presented regarding self-defense in a criminal case until the defense meets a burden of production to show that self-defense is an issue presented in a case, even if the ultimate burden of proof once the burden of production is satisfied and the issue goes to a jury is on the prosecution.

Comment: Do you mean, presumably, that the prosecution is burdened to show the self-defense was NOT an issue?